# In the figure,O is the centre of a circle and BCD is tangent to it at C. Prove that ∠BAC + ∠ACD = 90°.

Tags: circles

[image]

I am a beginner to these type of questions relating to tangents .....
Thats all.

Comment: $\angle BAC = \angle PCB$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$BC$ is tangent, we have 
$$\angle OCD=90^\circ$$

$OA=OC$, so $\angle OAC=\angle OCA$. Hence

$$\angle BAC+\angle ACD= \angle OCA+\angle ACD=\angle OCD=90^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT : By [alternate segment theorem](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/circles2hirev10.shtml), 
$$\angle PCB=\angle BAC.$$
Also, since two triangles $COA, COP$ are isosceles triangles, we have
$$\angle OCA=\angle OAC, \angle POC=2\angle PCB.$$

Hence, 
$$\begin{align}\angle{BAC}+\angle{ACD}&=\angle OCA+\angle ACD\\&=180^\circ-(\angle PCB+\angle PCO)\\&=180^\circ -\{\angle PCB+(180^\circ-2\angle PCB)/2\}\\&=180^\circ-90^\circ\\&=90^\circ.\end{align}$$